# Graham scan implementation in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, computational-geometry

It looks like this is a [really](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/implementation-of-graham-scan-algorithm-in-haskell) [classical](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31285/graham-scan-convex-hull-algorithm) [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68914/2d-convex-hull-exercise), but I'd like to ask it one more time as all those solutions look quite long and complicated for me (maybe because I am dumb :) )

So this is a Graham convex hull algorithm from the very beginning of the "Real World Haskell" book. And a perimeter function just for the sake of implementing it.

Why did the authors define the `Direction` datatype when it only acts like
`Ordering`?

Is there any more elegant way to traverse through lists considering pairs?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
import Text.Printf
import Data.List (sortBy)
data Point = Point Int Int deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

turn :: Point -> Point -> Point -> Ordering
turn (Point x2 y2) (Point x1 y1) (Point x3 y3) = compare ((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)) 0

polarSort :: [Point] -> [Point]
polarSort points = sorted where
    pivot = minimum points
    sorted = pivot:(sortBy (\a b -> turn b pivot a) . filter (pivot /=)) points

grahamScan :: [Point] -> [Point]
grahamScan points = grahamScan' rest [p2, p1] where
    (p1:p2:rest) = polarSort points
    grahamScan' [] l = l
    grahamScan' (p:pointsLeft) (s1:s2:selectedPoints) = case turn s2 s1 p of
                                        GT -> grahamScan' (p:pointsLeft) (s2:selectedPoints) -- the turn is right, so we discard last selected point
                                        _  -> grahamScan' pointsLeft (p:s1:s2:selectedPoints) -- the turn is left, so we add another point to the list of selected ones

dist :: Point -> Point -> Double
dist (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) = sqrt (fromIntegral ((x2 - x1)^(2 :: Int) + (y2 - y1)^(2 :: Int)))

perimeter :: [Point] -> Double
perimeter points@(p0:_) = dist p0 pn + rest where
    walk :: [Point] -> (Double, Point)
    walk [a] = (0, a)
    walk (p1:p2:ps) = (dist p1 p2 + next, lastPoint) where
        (next, lastPoint) = walk (p2:ps)
    (rest, pn) = walk points

main = do
    _ <- getLine
    content <- getContents
    putStrLn $ printf "%.1f" ((perimeter . grahamScan . map ((\([x, y]) -> Point x y) . map read . words) . lines) content)
```

Comment: Why are your points limited to `Int` coordinates?

Comment: Regarding `Direction`, the reason is semantics. Ordering means something different than direction and the meaning should be reflected in naming.

Answer (score 1):

### A good foundation to build on

One nice thing about your code is that it needs no `[arccos,arctan,arg,atan2,phase]`-like floating point approximations until you already have your convex hull and demand its Euclidean perimeter and another that you got the Graham scan's stack shuffle pretty concise and \$\mathcal O(n)\$ everywhere outside the one and only \$\mathcal O(n \log n)\$ `sortBy`.

#### with a glitch

The worst thing to say about your code is that it is only partially correct and easily confusable by collinear `EQ` triples: Just to give an example proof of failure, instead of the correct 4·4=`16.0` perimeter it calculates **incorrect** `20.5` perimeter for input point sample sequence

```
0 0
4 0
1 0
2 0
4 4
0 4
```

#### and other inelegances calling for a rewrite:

Aesthetically, your lambdas

```
(\a b -> turn b pivot a)
(\([x, y]) -> Point x y)
```

make me want to flip your argument order and core data type so that we get

```
compareFrom o l r=compare((x l-x o)*(y r-y o))((y l-y o)*(x r-x o))
```

mnemonically returning `LT` iff from `o` `l` looks "lefter than" = "left to" = "less right than" `r`,  for example `compareFrom (0,0) (1,2) (2,1) == LT` [to answer your question about the need for `data Direction=LEFT|STRAIGHT|RIGHT` **aliases**] and together with a

```
distanceFrom from to = ((x to-x from)**2+(y to-y from)**2)**(1/2)
```

handy not only to reduce your over-individualized `perimeter` to a one-liner

```
totalDistance ps = sum(zipWith distanceFrom(last ps:init ps)ps)
```

but also to get your Graham **preparation** to lambda-free (but oververbosely pointed)

```
convexHull points =
    let{o = minimum points; -- maximum/By comparing sum would be equally fine
        presorted=sortBy(compareFrom o)(filter(/=o)points);
        collinears=groupBy(((EQ==).).compareFrom o)presorted;
        outmost=map(maximumBy(comparing(distanceFrom o)))collinears;
    }in dropConcavities[o]outmost
```

so that we can now easily catch all cases in the final convexity **scan**

```
dropConcavities (left:lefter) (right:righter:rightest) =
    case compareFrom left right righter of
    LT -> dropConcavities (right:left:lefter) (righter:rightest)
    EQ -> dropConcavities (left:lefter) (righter:rightest)
    GT -> dropConcavities lefter (left:righter:rightest)
dropConcavities output lastInput = lastInput++output
```

By hitherto restricting myself to abstract `x` and `y` **accessor methods** i can now take the postponed liberal pick of any representation for which i can provide such functions:

```
import Data.Ord;import Data.List;(x,y)=((!!0),(!!1));
compareFrom o l r=compare((x l-x o)*(y r-y o))((y l-y o)*(x r-x o));
distanceFrom from to = ((x to-x from)**2+(y to-y from)**2)**(1/2);
totalDistance ps = sum(zipWith distanceFrom(last ps:init ps)ps);
convexHull points =
    let{o = minimum points;
        presorted=sortBy(compareFrom o)(filter(/=o)points);
        collinears=groupBy(((EQ==).).compareFrom o)presorted;
        outmost=map(maximumBy(comparing(distanceFrom o)))collinears;
    }in dropConcavities[o]outmost;
dropConcavities (left:lefter) (right:righter:rightest) =
    case compareFrom left right righter of{
    LT -> dropConcavities (right:left:lefter) (righter:rightest);
    EQ -> dropConcavities (left:lefter) (righter:rightest);
    GT -> dropConcavities lefter (left:righter:rightest);}
dropConcavities output lastInput = lastInput++output;
main = interact(show.totalDistance.convexHull.map(map read.words).lines);
```

Comment: I've changed the big-O-notation format. By the way, it doesn't really matter whether you use \$\log_2\$ or any other \$\log_n, n \in \mathbb R_+\$, since they only differ by some constant, which gets handled by the notation already.

Comment: I tend to prefer utf-8 plaintext over more convoluted frameworks and used the subscript two as kind of no-break space.

Comment: I presume you also prefer \$\mathcal O(\exp n)\$ over \$\mathcal O(2^n)\$, **O(2ⁿ)**, **O(₂n)**, or **(ℯⁿ)**.

Comment: No, I'd prefer (2ⁿ), but that depends on the context.